# Return http status code in component from Service - Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm having a problem in returning an object in my Http Service in catch to my component:

Here is my code in my service:

```
login(username,password){
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');

        return this.http.post(this.configEnvironment.url() + "oauth/access_token",
            JSON.stringify(
                {
                    username: username,
                    password: password,
                    grant_type: "password",
                    client_id: "xxxx",
                    client_secret: "xxxxx"
                }
            ),
            { headers }
        )
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch((err:Response) => {
            let details = err.json();

            return Observable.throw(details);
         });

     }
```

Here's my code in my component:

```
this.loginService.login(this.model.username,this.model.password)
            .subscribe(
                data => console.log(data),
                error => {
                    // var details = error.json();
                    console.log(error);
                },
                ()  =>  console.log("Finished")
            );
```

It works fine when I just return the json error like this:

```
let details = err.json();
    return Observable.throw(details);
```

But when I try to add the http response status code like this:

```
return  { status: err.status, error: Observable.throw(details) }
```

It gives me an error of:

*"Argument of type '(err: Response) => { status: number; error: ErrorObservable; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable) => ObservableInput'.
  Type '{ status: number; error: ErrorObservable; }' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.
    Type '{ status: number; error: ErrorObservable; }' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<{}>'.
      Property 'length' is missing in type '{ status: number; error: ErrorObservable; }'."*

My goal is just to include the http response code in the return of catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try below code,

```
.catch((err:Response) => {
            let details = {detail:err.json(),status: err.status};
            return Observable.throw(details);
 });
```

Comment: Welcome. Just want to inform you, yesterday you asked one question and I replied. Answer was correct and immediately you erased it. Never do it as it might help other users to figure out problem & solution if they come across the same situation.

Comment: Oops, sorry Man and yes will never do it again. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

simply try this one

```
return  [{ status: err.status, error: err.json() }]
```

this should work

or also you can simply send the whole `err` object in catch block and at the time of subscribing check the status code this one also works.

```
 return  err
```

and at the time of subscribe use

`err.status`

Comment: its okii, glad to hear you got your answer, you may try mine one too as alternate :)